# Getting values from a file that are not stored in two other lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

I have a *.xvg file and 3 different groups I want to store in 3 lists. First 2 groups have common traits so it is okay to use **line.startswith()** command. However, 3rd list is much longer and will differ, so I want to create a list from values that are not in list1 nor list2.

I tried not in **not in** but I guess something goes wrong with reading the file since it stores no value.

```
for line in open(name):

    if line.startswith(' 4755') or line.startswith(' 4756') or line.startswith(' 4759') or line.startswith(' 4760'):      
        l = line.split()
        arm1.append(float(l[1]))
        sum1= sum(arm1[0:len(arm1)])                


    elif line.startswith(' 4768') or line.startswith(' 4769') or line.startswith(' 4770') or line.startswith(' 4771') or line.startswith(' 4772') or line.startswith(' 4773') or line.startswith(' 4783') :     
        l = line.split()
        arm2.append(float(l[1]))
        sum2= sum(arm2[0:len(arm2)])

    if line not in [arm1] or [arm2]:

        l = line.split()
        arm3.append(float(l[1]))
        sum3= sum(arm3[0:len(arm3)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very efficient, but you can check if the line is in either list by making a combined list and checking if the line is there or not.

```
elif line not in arm1 + arm2 and line.startswith(' '):
        l = line.split()
        arm3.append(float(l[1]))
        sum3= sum(arm3[0:len(arm3)])
```

The problem I had with this code line was that my document also included introductory comment section thereby float values were not read. I have only added `elif line not in arm1 + arm2 and line.startswith(' '):` which solved the problem.

Even though it is simple, I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Maybe my logic is a bit weird since I am a beginner. @rdas this gives me ValueError: invalid literal for float()

Comment: Check `l[1]` it's probably not what you expect it be

Comment: You were right. There was a comment section that was also included in the file and was part of calculation as well. Now I only have to figure out how to skip all of that without having to delete it.